# Memory usage of client side web programming

Tags: memory, web, client

I am new at web programming and learning concepts. I have a question about client-side programming. I have a database for my web site and I do not want it to be queried unnecessarily by the users. To do this I want some informations like an integer array to be stored on client machine and used as foreknowledge to walk on the website. Otherwise user has to retrieve this information from database on every click which exhaust server. I want this information to be stored from the opening of web site until web site is closed. I thought javascript does such things but I am not sure about that javascript stores informations for period web site is open, in other saying datas stored in variables may be lost when change page while walking on the site. If you guide me about this issue I will be happy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not just put the information in a page retrieved by HTTP and let the browser's cache do its job?

Comment: I will store beginning id of all pages for rows. User will retrieve pages when it is necessary not all of the rows. I do not want this id array be retrieved by user all time when he/she changes page.Thanks

Comment: Then put the information in several pages retrieved by HTTP, as needed, and let the browser's cache do its job.

Comment: It make sense now, I will try it. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, You cant access the client machine for reading/storing informations from website provided if you are using certified flash plugin. 
you could store these static informations in browser cookie provided its not secure data.
Cookie could be accessed using javascript.

Comment: I also keep in mind cookie mechanism but it is size-limited and not convenient to store a data structure I think. I don't know much about it, maybe convenient, I will learn later. I just wanted to learn general way to do such things from experts.

Comment: In javascript we are able to define an array. Can we make it global such that it will not be lost until exit to website?

Comment: You could try the option of [web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) in html5. Actually all those global javascript variables will be available in page scope only. Once you refresh the page, those values will be lost.

Comment: Hmm Thank you, this was what I am curious about.

Comment: All please note that latest browsers only will support html5 and still users using older versions of browsers.